# How you can use kinect camera inside google chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, kinect

**EDIT**: It's [now supported](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410202)

I want to use a kinect inside of chrome using webrtc. <strike>In linux [`UYVY` is not supported](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=3765#makechanges)</strike>.

Is it possible to create a new device descriptor (/dev/video1) transforming /dev/video0 from `UYVY` to `YUYV`?

Comment: this look promising http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5452/manipulating-dev-video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to create a virtual device (loopback)

```
git clone git@github.com:umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
cd v4l2loopback
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback // creates /dev/video2 or /dev/videox ...
```

install gstreamer

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10
```

convert from sRGB to YUY2 (YUYV)

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! \
   ffmpegcolorspace ! \
   video/x-raw-rgb ! \
   ffmpegcolorspace ! \
   video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)YUY2 ! \
   v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

test if everything works

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! xvimagesink

v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 --all
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : v4l2 loopback
    Card type     : Dummy video device (0x0000)
    Bus info      : v4l2loopback:0
    Driver version: 0.8.0
    Capabilities  : 0x05000001
        Video Capture
        Read/Write
        Streaming
Video input : 0 (loopback: ok)
Video output: 0 (loopback in)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height  : 1280/1024
    Pixel Format  : 'YUYV'
    Field         : None
    Bytes per Line: 2560
    Size Image    : 2621440
    Colorspace    : SRGB
Format Video Output:
    Width/Height  : 1280/1024
    Pixel Format  : 'YUYV'
    Field         : None
    Bytes per Line: 2560
    Size Image    : 2621440
    Colorspace    : SRGB
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30000/1000)
    Read buffers     : 8
Streaming Parameters Video Output:
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30000/1000)
    Write buffers    : 8
                    keep_format (bool)   : default=0 value=0
              sustain_framerate (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                        timeout (int)    : min=0 max=100000000 step=1 default=0 value=0
               timeout_image_io (bool)   : default=0 value=0
```

Now this should work in chrome via Dummy video device (0x0000)

[image: kinect capture smilling]

Comment: You look so happy to have found the solution!

Comment: Haha yeah I was hacking this for 3 days straight. I learned a lot from video encoding from this. Like that vp8/vp9 codect does not really support realtime streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the answer from 2014.
`gst-launch-1.0` has some flags, so the new command to be used, and which worked for me, is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! \
           videoconvert ! \
           video/x-raw, format=RGB ! \
           videoconvert ! \
           video/x-raw,format=YUY2 ! \
           v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

where `/dev/video1` is the loopback device.